# Simultaneous condition on all line elements of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple in the following format:

```
[(None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 15, 0)), (None, None),
 (None, None), (None, None), (None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 16, 0))]
```

I want to iterate over the tuple, check if both components are null and if so remove them from the item — leaving only these:

```
[(None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 15, 0)),
 (None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 16, 0))]
```

What's the neatest way to perform the checks in a single loop at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
output_list = filter(any, input_list)
```

Comment: You can use just `any` instead of `lambda t: any(t)`.

Comment: Nice answer, the others work too but this is what I was looking for

Comment: As an extra, what if I only wanted to get rows where all items are None?

Comment: `output_list = filter(lambda t: not any(t), input_list)`

Comment: Using a list comprehension, as shown in other answers, would work unchanged in both Python 2 & 3 -- assuming goal is to actually produce an output list. It might also execute faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension and tuple unpacking:

```
>>> lst = [(None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 15, 0)), (None, None),
... (None, None), (None, None), (None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 16, 0))]
>>> [(a,b) for a,b in lst if a or b]
[(None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 15, 0)),
 (None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 16, 0))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list comprehension and [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

```
left = [x for x in a if any(x)]
>> [(None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 15, 0)), (None, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 14, 16, 0))]
```